# Positioning DIVs with Position:absolute elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Consider following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AsGk4/

As you can see the two boxes overlap instead of being positioned next to each other with `float:left` property. When I remove the child `.text` DIV, the boxes appear as they should. I assume this behavior comes from `.text` 's `position:absolute` property, but why does this have impact on parent DIV's appearance?

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class='text'><span>Some text</span><div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class='text'><span>Some text</span><div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#0000FF;
    float:left;
}
.box:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 1%;
    top: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:9px;
    left:5px;
    width: 95%;
    text-align:left;
}
.text span {
    color: white;
    font: bold 12px/16px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:1px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Silly me, forgot to close the div tags. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need `float: left;` if you are using `display: inline-block;` and vice versa..

If you are using `float` then don't forget to `clear` them and if you are sticking with `display: inline-block;` then I assume you will need `vertial-align: top;` as they are aligned to *baseline* by default. So use any one, as using both seems redundant

Also it's worth noting that using `display: inline-block;` will cause you white-space

And what's the issue? You are *not closing* your `div` tags, [there are many ways to deal with that](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AsGk4/2/)

---

If you want to refactor your code, the below snippet

```
padding: 1px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-right:1px;
```

Can be written as `padding: 1px 1px 1px 3px;` which is nothing but shorthand syntax

Comment: Voopsy, silly me! That's what happens if you don't sleep for two days in a row. apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Close the text divs and it works just fine.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class='text'><span>Some text</span></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class='text'><span>Some text</span></div>
</div>
```

See [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AsGk4/1/)

Comment: Voopsy, silly me! That's what happens if you don't sleep for two days in a row. apologies.

Answer (score 1):

your closing `<div>` tags aren't closing - you need to change them to `</div>`. This is causing the boxes to nest inside of one another rather than being side by side.